# 'NoSuchMethodException' even though the method really does exist

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, nosuchmethoderror

**fragment_view1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:text="First View"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewOneBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Click Here" />

  <include layout = "@layout/drop_down"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**drop_down.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical" 

        android:alpha="0.7">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="^^^"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_inquiry"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="AAA" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onMenuItemClicked" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_event"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="BBB" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_additional_info"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="CCC"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_to_contacts"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="DDD" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FirstView.java** (for fragment_view1.xml)

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstView extends DropDownMenu
{
    private TextView firstText;
    private Button btn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,container,false);


        firstText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneText);
        btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneBtn);

        return view;

    }



}
```

**DropDownMenu.java** (for drop_down.xml)

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DropDownMenu extends Fragment {

    private TextView addInquiry, addEvent, additionalInfo, addToContacts;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drop_down,container,false);
        intialize();
        return view;

    }

    private void intialize()
    {

        //Intializing instance variables
        addInquiry = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_add_inquiry);
        addEvent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_add_event);
        additionalInfo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_additional_info);
        addToContacts = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_add_to_contacts);

    }



    public void onMenuItemClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.menu_add_inquiry:
           // Intent intent = new Intent(DropDownMenu.this,NewLead.class);
           // startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:;
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity  {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyAdapter pageAdapter;
    private static final int ITEMS = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pageAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position==0)
            {
                return new FirstView();
            }
            else
            {
                return new SecondView();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
    }

}
```

This code generate the following UI. Note that what you see as a "Menu" is built by `drop_down.xml`.

[image]

The problem is, when I click the `TextView` *menu_add_inquiry* in *drop_down.xml*, I get the following error.

```
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onMenuItemClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'menu_add_inquiry'
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onMenuItemClicked [class android.view.View]
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
11-28 14:13:52.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     ... 11 more
```

It says that method is missing, but it is there.

**UPDATE**

I edited the button in *drop_down.xml* with the full definition `com.example.fragmenttest.DropDownMenu.onMenuItemClicked`. Now I have the following issue

> 11-28 14:49:45.757: E/AndroidRuntime(2604): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.fragmenttest.DropDownMenu.onMenuItemClicked [class android.view.View]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `drop_down.xml` layout, you call onMenuItemClicked method, that does not exist in MainActivity class.

In the case of your layout, it is the method of the activity that will be called (and not the one of the fragment).

You may want to replace your method by same method, but in your MainActivity class.

You may read documentation of Android [android:onclick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) :

> This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) **method of your context (typically, your Activity)**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunatly it didn't solve the issue. Please have a look at my update.